# Convert 'array of pointers to arrays' to 'array of pointers to the first elements'

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, language-lawyer

I have an array of pointers to arrays:

```
int a1[6] = { 3, 7, 2, 4, 9, 8 };
int a2[6] = { 4, 8, 3, 0, 3, 5 };
int a3[6] = { 1, 7, 2, 3, 9, 2 };
int (*a[3])[6] = { &a1, &a2, &a3 };
```

and the following function that expects "a pointer to the first element of an array[3] of pointers pointing to the first elements of array[6]s":

```
void foo(int **pp) {
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j < 6; ++j) {
            std::cout << pp[i][j] << ", ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

This works:

```
int *b[3] = { a1, a2, a3 };
foo(b);
```

But I can't find a way to pass `a` to `foo`.

To me, it seems quite natural for "array of pointers to arrays" to be converted to "array of pointers to the first element of the individual arrays". Just as an array can be converted to a pointer to its first element.

To support this argument, `foo(reinterpret_cast<int **>(a))` prints the same output as `foo(b)` in my environment.

Is it possible to convert `int (*[3])[6]` to `int *[3]` using only `static_cast`s?
If not, is `foo(reinterpret_cast<int **>(a))` well defined by the standard?

Comment: There's no way for `a` to be converted or to decay to the type you want. The solution is to either change the signature of `foo` to accept what you want to pass, or to change `a` to something which can be passed to `foo` (like the array `b`).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Can `a` be changed to the type I want without copying the original `a`?

Comment: What are your requirements on `a`? What limitations are specified for your assignment? Why does it have to be an array of pointers to arrays (instead of an array of pointers to `int` as for `b`)? Why can't you use `b` instead?

Comment: As for the decay rules, it's rather simple: An array decays to a pointer to its first element. So `a` decays to `&a[0]`. And since `a[0]` have the type `int (*)[6]` then `&a[0]` will have the type `int (**)[6]`. Which is really even further from the wanted `int **` type.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I will say the reverse :) Why `foo` takes a `int**` whereas it has size requirements.

Comment: _Is it possible to convert int (*[3])[6] to int *[3] using only static_casts?_ How do you think `reinterpret_cast<int**>(a)` is defined?

Comment: _If not, is `foo(reinterpret_cast<int **>(a))` well defined by the standard?_ No, `f` would violate https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.add#6.sentence-1

Comment: @LanguageLawyer. I do not understand the relevance of your link. Maybe I look in the wrong spot. Anyway: A pointer is an address in memory. And a pointer can be cast to any other pointer. It is then still a pointer. Same address. So the value of the pointer is unchanged. Only the interpretation of the data at this address may change. If the data at this address can be interpreted as wished, then it is OK

Comment: @ArminMontigny "And a pointer can be cast to any other pointer" is wrong, as it could break strict aliasing. Besides, the layout of how different objects are stored in memory differs. An array of pointers to arrays will not be stored the same as an array of arrays.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude _"And a pointer can be cast to any other pointer" is wrong, as it could break strict aliasing_ Strict aliasing rule is about **accessing** objects through **glvalues**. Not about casting pointers.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer You do your name justice... ;) But casting pointers willy-nilly is **a** slippery slope (one of many) leading to accessing the wrong objects and strict aliasing problems.

Comment: I stick with my statement that a pointer can be cast to any other pointer. The interpretation of data will fail. But the pointer can be cast: ````#include <iostream>
class A{};
class B{};

int main() {
    A a; A* aptr = &a;
    B* bptr = reinterpret_cast<B*>(aptr);
    std::cout << aptr << '\t' << bptr;
    return 0;
}````

Comment: @ArminMontigny No idea where your beliefs come from, but it is not how C++ works.

Comment: @ArminMontigny _I stick with my statement that a pointer can be cast to any other pointer_ It can, but what can you do with the resulting pointer may be limited.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I guess there's no other way but to copy the elements one by one. It's just that a part of me had a superstition that there is always a workaround in what might seem like a limitation of the language itself.